# Ext Js Ajax call response

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am working with Ext Js Ajax calls. I am specifying a URL in as the `url:` value which will redirect to some other URL after execution. What my question is, is there anyway to know the new redirected URL..??

I tried with `data.responseText` and i failed to retrieve the new URL. Next I used `JSON.stringify(data)` method, and i get the URL which I passed when using this  *Ajax Call* , not the new  **redirected**  one.

**Note:**  I cant use a browser to open the URL to see the new one, since it opens a new Browser window..

**CODE:**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myAppId&' +
        'response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com' +
        '/connect/login_success.html',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data, status) {
        Ext.Msg.alert(data.responseText);
        if (data.responseText=='Success') {
            // Here i need to use the new redirected URL
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Post the ajax call code

Comment: I updated my code..! Plz have a look !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
success:function(xhr,textstatus) {
    // xhr.responseText contains the response from the server
    var allheaders = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
    // this will get all headers as a string - if you want them as an object...
    var eachheader = allheaders.split('\n');
    var headers = {};
    for(i = 0; i < eachheader.length; i++) {
        if ($.trim(eachheader[i]) !== '') {
            headersplit = eachheader[i].split(':');
            headers[headersplit[0]]=$.trim(headersplit[1]);
        }
    }
  }
```

Got this from this question:

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666205/jquery-ajax-form-how-to-get-the-redirect-url)

Comment: I get the HTTP ver. and all but no the new redirect URL..!! :( have you any other suggestions??

Comment: Alert the entire thing and extract what you need.

Comment: Alert `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();` and check that.

Comment: Yes man, I did that. & I get some info, when i go through that, i cant find anything like an expected URL..!!!

Comment: Then I really have no idea. Search along these lines.

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` could you plz check this url. Then you could find that initially it shows a page ( which i needs ) and within seconds the URL changes to something like this `https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_`. I thing the problem why I cant get the expected result is due to this. plz have A look at this..!